# Using a const variable in django

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

Whenever I try to define a 'const' variable in a django template I am told that its already been declared when I didn't declare it anywhere.  I cannot find any material on this.

This is what I have in my Django Template:

```
    <div>
      <li class="color">Blue</li>
      <li class="color">Red</li>
      <li class="color">Green</li>
      <li class="color">None</li>
    <div>
```

The CSS reads like this:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
```

The JavaScript reads like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const colorLines = document.querySelectorAll('.color');
        colorLines.forEach(element => {
            if (element.innerHTML == "None") {
                element.classList.add('hidden');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

The aim is to not show anything if "None" is typed in.  I know the JavaScript above works I've made a similar HTML file to it stand alone and its just fine.  Django doesn't allow const or let for some reason and I can't find why not.  And if I try var it throws no errors but still no outcome.   I checked the same code outside of django.  I can't seem to find what I am missing.

Comment: You should be ok to use let or var for the variable. You're getting the error with const because you're attempting to modify the elements inside the colorLines variable.

Comment: Most likely you're using `extends` or `include` in your templates and have that piece of code repeated.

Comment: Thanks.  Just changing it to variable worked.